# Replace wp-content folder in wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress

I have replaced wordpress content folder wp-content folder with a new folder and deleted the old one.But the new one does not work even after renaming it wp-content.I have found few sources which ask me to configure wp-settings.php or wp-config.php but making the changes did'nt work.Please somebody tell me what is the exact procedure to change the content folder.

Comment: Here you can get detailed article regarding the change of wp-content and uploads.- http://www.kvcodes.com/2013/12/rename-wp-content-folder-and-uploads-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Before you make any changes, make a **backup** of your site.

Open `wp-config.php` and add this:

```
define ( 'WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME', 'your-new-folder-name' );
define ( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME );
define ( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );  
define ( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_SITEURL . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME );
```

This solution is taken from: [How to Rename Your WordPress wp-content Directory](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/renaming-wordpress-wp-content-folder/)

**Note:** I would recommend against renaming this folder. As that tutorial points out, you may come across plugins that don't follow best practices and link to `/wp-content/` manually. This may result in that plugin not functioning properly.

Answer (score 0):

use below code :

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined(‘ABSPATH’) )
define(‘ABSPATH’, dirname(__FILE__) . ‘/’);
```

Add this:

```
define (‘WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME’, ‘cdnDIR’); // replace cdndir with your custom directory name.
define (‘WP_CONTENT_DIR’, ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME) ;
define(‘WP_SITEURL’, ‘http://’ . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . ‘/’);
define(‘WP_CONTENT_URL’, WP_SITEURL . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);
define( ‘WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE’, true );
```

Source by: http://www.tutsapp.com/how-to-change-wp-content-folder-name-wp-content-and-upload-path.html